# JS if else if else

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Is there a way to run multiple if else statements from one event? For example, trying to run this, but it's only executing the first if else for the element with class "two" and not the second element which has class "three".

```
$(".hamburger-menu").click(function(){

    if ($(".two").hasClass("two-rotate")){
        $(".two").addClass("two-rotate-back").removeClass("two-rotate");
    } 
    else {
        $(".two").addClass("two-rotate").removeClass("two-rotate-back");
    }

    // This one won't execute
    if ($(".three").hasClass("three-rotate")){
        $(".three").addClass("three-rotate-back").removeClass("three-rotate");
    }
    else {
        $(".three").addClass("three-rotate").removeClass("three-rotate-back");
    }
});
```

I know the answer must be a simple one, but I've been searching for 30 minutes now and can't find the answer.

Comment: are you seeing any error message in your console? and does element with `.three` class actually exists?

Comment: How have you determined that the code is not executing?

Comment: To verify, put an alert("HERE"); after .two code finishes to make sure it is working or not.  Maybe an error is raising?  Also, you could try to put in alert($(".three").length) to make sure that it's finding it.

Comment: "Is there a way to run multiple if else statements from one event?" - Yes, there's nothing wrong with your logic. Have you stepped through it in the debugger?

Comment: There's no `});` at the end of the handler. Is it missing? Or did you just omit it from the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yeah, just forgot to paste over the "});".

Comment: your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/61hbzhnp/ Please  post the related HTML too

Comment: @BrianMains Hmmm.... seems the alert is firing on all three. Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/keenanerwin/pen/RPVROm

Comment: @Dr.Molle it must be my css, but I don't see how codepen.io/keenanerwin/pen/RPVROm

Comment: @KeenanErwin can't figure it out.  If you add this at the end:   `$(".three").toggleClass("hide", 1000);` it hides the class, so that operation works, just not rotation.  I'm out of ideas....

Comment: Found the issue in the css with naming one of the animations incorrectly. SO so embarrassed. Sorry guys. At the very least I learned how to debug better. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is missing
`});`   at the end and also the click event may not be correctly binding.

Here is the working plunkr :"http://plnkr.co/edit/6hBXDFLXoGkHFBgvmbbx?p=preview"

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing correctly your code.

Put the `});` at the end.

When you need to debug some code, you could do something like that:

```
if ( someExpression ) {

    // logic here...
    console.log( 'passed through if' );   

} else {

    // logic here...
    console.log( 'passed through else' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you figured out your problem, but I just wanted to mention that if the `-rotate` and `-rotate-back` classes are mutually exclusive as they appear to be in your code, you could replace those `if` statements with a couple of short [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) statements:

```
$(".hamburger-menu").click(function(){
    $(".two").toggleClass("two-rotate-back two-rotate");
    $(".three").toggleClass("three-rotate-back three-rotate");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/hc4Ldm9n/